# Flex custom component doesn't accept Script: Multiple initializer values for default property, 'text', of type 'String'

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm using Flex 4 and Flash Builder 4. I just want to learn to create components and I created an mxml component as follows and included it in my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TextInput xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
    </fx:Script>
</s:TextInput>
```

If I take out the fx:Script tags it works, but as soon as I have those tags (regardless of whether any actual code is in there) I get the error: "Flex custom component doesn't accept script: Multiple initializer values for default property, 'text', of type 'String'."

Why would that be? Is script not allowed in components?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this is a known bug [SDK-25184](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25184). Milestone is the next Flex SDK Hero Release. You still can use mxml if you explicitly set the **text** property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TextInput xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
             text="">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:TextInput>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you change `TextInput` to `Button` it will be OK.

The problem is that `TextInput` treats `Script` as a value for `text` property. I believe it is a compiler bug.

Comment: ahh, ok. It also gives errors for fx:Declarations by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Another way around this is to extend TextInput using actionscript rather than mxml:

```
package
{
    import spark.components.TextInput;

    public class TestTextInput extends TextInput
    {
        public function TestTextInput()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```