# How to create a custom Flex 4 button with 3 labels

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I would like to create a custom Button component with three labels: left-, center-, and right-justified. I can't just use the label justification property, because I want to use all 3 labels at the same time.

I'm familiar with creating custom components, but I've never tried to build one quite like this before...

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Button 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var labelContentL:String;
            private var labelContentC:String;
            private var labelContentR:String;

            public function set labelL(value:String):void
            {
                labelContentL = value;
            }
            public function set labelC(value:String):void
            {
                labelContentC = value;
            }
            public function set labelR(value:String):void
            {
                labelContentR = value;
            }

            public function get labelL():String
            {
                return labelContentL;
            }
            public function get labelC():String
            {
                return labelContentC;
            }
            public function get labelR():String
            {
                return labelContentR;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="l" width="100%" text="{labelContentL}" textAlign="left" paddingLeft="10" />
    <s:Label id="c" width="100%" text="{labelContentC}" textAlign="center" />
    <s:Label id="r" width="100%" text="{labelContentR}" textAlign="right" paddingRight="10" />

</s:Button>
```

The labels won't change after the button is created, so I'm not worried about the missing `[Bindable]` metadata.

I'm stuck right now, getting the following compiler error:

> Multiple initializer values for default property, 'label', of type 'String'.

...for each of the 3 `<s:Label>` lines.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139486/flex-custom-component-doesnt-accept-script-multiple-initializer-values-for-defa/4699805#4699805) to a similar question, I tried adding `label=""` to my `<s:Button>` declaration, but that just adds another error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think the Button component would only accept a single instance of a label, hence, the error. I wonder though how you plan on using a button with 3 labels which are aligned in L, C and R.

Comment: @Angelo I'm only using a button because it is the simplest component that looks close to what I want and provides the functionality I need (click handling) without too much extra fluff. Here's a screenshot of the design spec that shows how it will be used: http://skit.ch/be4r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that a tag named label under the button tag isn't an item of type label, it's the label used on the button, and is of type string.

Why not do it as a skin, rather than a custom component?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<!-- host component -->
<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("ThreeLabelButton")]
</fx:Metadata>

<!-- states -->
<s:states>
    <s:State name="disabled" />
    <s:State name="down" />
    <s:State name="over" />
    <s:State name="up" />
</s:states>

<s:Rect bottomLeftRadiusX="5" 
        bottomRightRadiusX="5" 
        topLeftRadiusX="5" 
        topRightRadiusX="5" 
        top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color.up="#CCCCCC" color.over="#555555" color.down="#888888" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
<mx:Label id="leftLabel" text="{hostComponent.leftText}" left="0" />
<mx:Label id="rightLabel" text="{hostComponent.rightText}" right="0" />
<mx:Label id="centerLabel" text="{hostComponent.centerText}" left="{(this.width - centerLabel.width) / 2}" /> 
</s:Skin>
```

This will work with this class:

```
import mx.controls.Label;

import spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase;

public class ThreeLabelButtonComponent extends ButtonBase
{
    public function ThreeLabelButtonComponent()
    {
        super();
    }

    [SkinPart]
    public var leftLabel:Label;

    [SkinPart]
    public var rightLabel:Label;

    [SkinPart]
    public var centerLabel:Label;

            [Bindable]
    public var leftText:String;
            [Bindable]
    public var rightText:String;
            [Bindable]
    public var centerText:String;


    protected override function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void
    {
        super.partAdded(partName, instance);
        if(instance === leftLabel)
        {
            leftLabel.text = leftText;  
        }
        if(instance === rightLabel)
        {
            rightLabel.text = rightText;    
        }
        if(instance === centerLabel)
        {
            centerLabel.text = centerText;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you also need to subclass button to add the @SkinPart elements, so the skin has a source for the actual text to display. Also, you should put all three labels inside an HBox or similar.

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing it with a skin -- I'm already doing skinning, but the button is being used as an ItemRenderer for a list component, so the value has to be something that can be set onto the button, ala: `<s:Button skinClass="..." labelLeft="Left-text" labelRight="Right-text" />`. Your example uses static text. Can you show how I might get the values dynamically in an ItemRenderer?

Comment: @Adam Tuttle I've subclassed ButtonBase and added skinparts for the labels. See if that solves your problem.

Comment: I think I'm partly there. Aside from updating to Spark labels, I don't think I've changed much. Here's what I've got so far; but the labels are blank... Start with [the main file](https://gist.github.com/bdbe96306a2e21e446b9#file_main.mxml) which then uses the [item renderer](https://gist.github.com/bdbe96306a2e21e446b9#file_itemrenderer.contract_renderer.mxml), which uses the [custom class](https://gist.github.com/bdbe96306a2e21e446b9#file_components.three_label_button_component.as) and the [skin](https://gist.github.com/bdbe96306a2e21e446b9#file_skins.log_bar.mxml). Also included list skin.

Comment: When I say that "the labels are blank" what I mean is that no text is displayed. I even tried hard-coding their value to "test" in a few places but it never showed up.

Comment: I've added bindings to the text, which should solve your problem.